# R tsclean "Error in approx(idx, x[idx], tt, rule = 2) : need at least two non-NA values to interpolate" error when no NA values are present

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, forecast

The following code produces the error in the subject (assuming you've got `forecast` installed):

```
foo <- c(0.011033, 0.074117, 0.023965, 0.024718, 0.023735) 
forecast::tsclean(foo)
```

Even perturbing just one of the numbers by, say, 0.1, avoids the error. Strangely, the error also persists under affine transformations of the vector above (meaning you can add a constant to the entire vector and scale each value by the some constant as well and the error remains).

I'm running R 4.0.0 and the most recent development build of `forecast` (though the error occurred as well before I updated to the development build).

I'm aware that there was a previous, similar issue with constant vectors, but nothing that I can map to this. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tsclean()` works by first running `tsoutliers()` to find outliers in the series, and replacing them with NAs. Then it estimates the values of those outliers using a smooth trend model.

`tsoutliers()` is an iterative process. In this example, the first 2 observations are considered outliers in the first pass and replaced by NAs. On the second pass, the last 2 observations are considered outliers and replaced by NAs. Then there is only one non-NA observation left and the process fails.

I've fixed the problem in the dev version of the package on github. Now it gives the following result:

```r
foo <- c(0.011033, 0.074117, 0.023965, 0.024718, 0.023735)  
forecast::tsclean(foo) 
#> [1] 0.023965 0.023965 0.023965 0.023965 0.023965
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>